# How to remove last children from stack panel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I am adding children to my stackpanel dynamically. What I need is, I want to remove the last children for certain scenario. Is there any option to get last children?

Here is my code:

```
var row = new somecontrol();           
stackpanel.Children.Add(row);
```

Is there any possible way to remove children.lastOrDefault()?

```
stackpanel.Children.Last();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO you should not be doing this. Use Databinding to a ViewModel.
Besides that, you could just stackpanel.RemoveAt(stackpanel.Children.Count-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if(stackpanel.Children.Count != 0)
    stackpanel.Children.RemoveAt(stackpanel.Children.Count - 1);
```

...or if you want to use Linq, just use the `OfType<>` ExtensionMethod. Then you can do whatever with Linq you wish, like `LastOrDefault`:

```
var child = stackpanel.Children.OfType<UIElement>().LastOrDefault();
if(child != null)
    stackpanel.Children.Remove(child);
```

But, the first is probably fastest.

Or you can make your own Extension method, if you want:

```
class PanelExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveLast(this Panel panel)
    {
        if(panel.Children.Count != 0)
            panel.Children.RemoveAt(panel.Children.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Use like this

```
stackpanel.Children.RemoveLast();
```

But Like Xeun mentions an MVVM solution with Bindings would be preferable.