# WPF - Remove a "User Control" Child from a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a WPF UI where the user can edit a query to search the database. The query is created according to what the consumer chooses from the comboboxes [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ih0p.png) and he can create as much filters as he wants as long as he clicks the **Add new Condition** button.

I created the comboboxes template as a User Control like this :

User control XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button
                Name="DeleteFilter" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="5"
                Content="-"
            Click="DeleteFilter_OnClick">
        </Button>
        <ComboBox 
                Text="Property"
                x:Name="Property"
                Width="100"
                DataContext="{StaticResource SomeViewModel}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectionChanged="Property_OnSelectionChanged"/>
        <ComboBox 
            Text="PropertyOperator"
            x:Name="Operator"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Operators}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectionChanged="Operator_OnSelectionChanged">
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox 
                x:Name="Value"
                Text="Value"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                Width="100"
                Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Whenever the user clicks the **Add new Condition** button, I call this event:

```
private void AddFilterButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var conditionUserControl = new ConditionUserControl();
        StackPanel.Children.Add(conditionUserControl);
    }
```

Everything works correctly.

My Question:

How can I delete the User Control child from clicking the **DeleteFilter** [button that exists in the User Control template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiYG6.png).

I tried this:

```
StackPanel.Children.Remove(..);
```

to remove the child from my MainWindow but how to know which child the user clicked.

Comment: How does the button knows which child to remove? `StackPanel` doesn't provide you with `SelectedItem`.. unless you add buttons to each child or handle selection yourself somehow.. Do you simply want to [remove last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28208686/1997232)?

Comment: No, I want to remove whatever child the user clicks, is that possible? That's the point. I'm new to WPF and I dont know How to make this possible... Do you think its a good Idea to add the button to each created child?

Comment: *"add the button to each created child"* - it's totally fine. I didn't noticed that you already doing that. You can find user control containing button in the visual tree and delete that instance from `StackPanel`.

Comment: Instead of changing question you can post your solution as an answer. Using captured instances in lambda is a smart move.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will Do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void DeleteFilter_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var conditionUserControl = FindParent<ConditionUserControl>(btn);
    if (conditionUserControl != null)
    {
        var sp = FindParent<StackPanel>(conditionUserControl);
        if (sp != null)
            sp.Children.Remove(conditionUserControl);
    }
}


private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: I can't seam to understand the answer. AddFilterButton is supposed to add the child to the stack panel. Implementing what you suggests remove this functionality.. I'm new in WPF, apologies if I sound inconvenient.

Comment: Sorry, this is the implementation for the DeleteFilter_OnClick event handler. I changed the name.

Comment: I understand. AddFilter is a button  in a FilterWindow class, and DeleteFilter button is in another class called ConditionUserControl.. So, the StackPanel is not recognized.

Comment: Then you need to get a reference to the StackPanel. You could do this the same way, i.e. find it in the visual tree provided that the UC is a child of the SP. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to @mm8 answer is :

Update the AddFilterButton_OnClick:

I did this and the functionality works:

```
private void AddAndFilterButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var conditionUserControl = new ConditionUserControl();

        StackPanel.Children.Add(conditionUserControl);

        conditionUserControl.DeleteFilter.Click += (o, args) => StackPanel.Children.Remove(conditionUserControl);
    }
```