# PreviewMouseDown Intercepting SelectedItemChanged Event

Tags: wpf

I've got a `TreeView` which acts as the main way of navigating a WPF application.

When the user selects a new item in the `TreeView` if the page they're leaving has unsaved information we offer the chance to cancel the move to continue working on the current data/save it. This currently happens in the `PreviewMouseDown` event handler.

It seems however that throwing up a dialog that offers a yes/no/cancel option here prevents the `SelectedItemChanged` event from ever actually firing, I assume because another mouse click has occured. As a result, if they decline the option to stay on the current page, it's still not changing.

Is there any way to re-fire the event from within `PreviewMouseDown` so that the `SelectedItemChanged` event still gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to re-fire the event from within PreviewMouseDown so that the SelectedItemChanged event still gets called?

It would be easier to call the event handler manually just as you would call a method. Or better yet, break out the code in the event handler to a standalone method that you call from both the `PreviewMouseDown` handler and the `SelectedItemChanged` handler.

The other option would be to change the `SelectedItem` or `IsSelected` property so the event fires again.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I'm not sure I'll end up with the required information from the event I'm missing. The PreviewMouseDown event won't know what the new SelectedItem will be

Comment: You could figure out the item to be selected using the OriginalSource property of the MouseButtonEventArgs.

Comment: I can set the IsSelected on OriginalSourcce.DataContext and this works fine, unless I click the label in which cause my data context becomes the text in the label - can you traverse back up the tree from there?

Comment: See the FindParent in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693549/wpf-remove-a-user-control-child-from-a-stackpanel/45693663#45693663

Comment: Thanks. For my specific case I ended up manually crawling back up the tree, not pleasant but got the job done.